# Corda - IllegalArgumentException Don't know about party

Tags: corda

We are seeing this error coming back from an initiating node

```
I 17:49:50+0000 [Node thread-1] flow.[a3694ae6-ff1e-482e-af51-81cde48dbb94].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party O=Notary, L=London, C=GB. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=3291272982884783111). {}
W 17:49:50+0000 [Node thread-1] flow.[a3694ae6-ff1e-482e-af51-81cde48dbb94].run - Terminated by unexpected exception {}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know about party O=Notary, L=London, C=GB
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know about party O=Notary, L=London, C=GB

Is there a reason that the initiating node can't find the notary?

Comment: Can you debug into the flow and inspect the contents of the node's cache of the network map via the `ServiceHub`? What do they see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the local network map cache of the node via crash shell, using the command `run networkMapSnapshot` and check that the node can see the notary.